# Can I use SQLite in a commercial program?

Tags: sqlite

My application will be using the API of the public-domain SQLite library to dynamically create databases and input data automatically into those databases.

When I google and look at their licencing it says nothing about IP rights.

1. Do I need to email them and find out if I need to purchase a licence to publicly use their API within my commercial project/asset?
2. Do I need to collaborate with the company/person who created such API and have them collaborate and have a % in-take due to it being their work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and some other policy rather than a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Public domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Domain)" means that you can do whatever you want with it.

The [SQLite web site](http://www.sqlite.org/) has a [License](http://www.sqlite.org/copyright.html) link right at the top:

> All of the code and documentation in SQLite has been dedicated to the public domain by the authors. […] Anyone is free to copy, modify, publish, use, compile, sell, or distribute the original SQLite code, either in source code form or as a compiled binary, for any purpose, commercial or non-commercial, and by any means.